# I need Regular expression

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which can detect 5 consecutive occurrences of any digit or character as given in below examples :

A11111C2 – INVALID
AAAAAAA21 – INVALID
12AXXXXX – INVALID
GGGG112 – VALID

Comment: Not possible with Regex.

Answer (score 5):

You can match five consecutive characters with `(.)\1\1\1\1`. So `.*(.)\1\1\1\1.*` matches all your invalid cases.

The `\1` is a backreference, so it only matches *exactly* what the first group `(.)` matched.